# Google Places Service findPlaceFromPhoneNumber not returning any results

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I've built an interface where a prospect can type in their business name and the Places service uses AutoComplete **getPlace** method to get the business PlaceID. This works perfectly if the location has a published address.

However, if the business has no published address (just service areas), then AutoComplete can't find the business, so the fallback is **findPlaceByQuery** (sketchy at best because it defaults to locations with published addresses) and **findPlaceFromPhoneNumber** which apparently only works if the business has a published address.

The problem is that if you send a business phone number to the findPlaceFromPhoneNumber method, nothing shows up. Here's the code I'm using:

```
const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
service.findPlaceFromPhoneNumber({
    phoneNumber: '+19135550000',
    fields: ['ALL']
}, async(place, status) => {
    if(status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){
        console.log(place);
    } else {
        console.log('Error: no query results');
    }
});
```

Is there any way to get the PlaceID of a business that doesn't have an address listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such places are not available via Places API, there's a feature request for this:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/35828187 Support service area businesses